# mysql multiple data return

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database with two table tbllogout and tbllogin

in tbllogin i have 2 fields users_id and logsin(timestamp)
in tbllogout i have 2 fields also users_id and logsout(timestamp)
now both this table tbllogin & tbllogout contain two row data like below

this is for tbllogin

```
+---------------------------------------+
+---id---users_id---logsin--------------+
+---1----2015-------2015-11-23 10:27:23-+
+---2----2016-------2015-11-23 11:27:33-+                              
+---------------------------------------+
```

this is for tbllogout

```
+---------------------------------------+
+---id---users_id---logsout--------------+
+---2----2015-------2015-11-23 15:27:23-+
+---4----2016-------2015-11-23 15:47:33-+                              
+---------------------------------------+
```

now my asking is why is that when i try to select the data on both table it returns data more than the data it contains for example:

select logsin, logsout from logins, logouts  it will return the data

```
+---------------------------------------------+ 
+--logsin--------------+--logsout-------------+
+--2015-11-23 10:27:23-+-2015-11-23 10:27:37--+
+--2015-11-23 10:27:33-+-2015-11-23 10:27:37--+
+--2015-11-23 10:27:23-+-2015-11-23 10:27:41--+
+--2015-11-23 10:27:33-+-2015-11-23 10:27:41--+
+---------------------------------------------+
```

how is that possible that is returns 4 row where infact there are only two row on each table tbllogsin where did it get the extra data that it returns? i try distinct but did not work also group by it only group the first column and not the second when you use it on both it will just display one column

what i want is for my query to display only the value that my database contain

Comment: You're using the wrong join in your query.

Comment: so anik islam abhi that do you think is the right query

Comment: so tel me what is the rgith qury

Comment: can you show your query ?

Comment: select logsin, logsout from logins, logouts

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are searching for.

```
select i.logsin, o.logsout FROM tbllogin i, tbllogout o where i.users_id = o.users_id
```

Comment: logsin                          logsout
2015-11-23 13:51:25 2015-11-23 13:54:40
2015-11-23 13:51:25 2015-11-23 13:55:04                                                                it still return duplicate data observe logsin

Comment: jr. captain output is still duplicating

Answer (score 0):

i figure out myself `SELECT COUNT(*) AS`Rows`,`FullName`as`Employee Name:`,`Logsin`as`Time In:`,`Logsout`as`Time Out:`,`TimeRendered`FROM`qdata`GROUP BY`Logsin`ORDER BY`Logsin